Changes Not Showing After Merging Release Branch into Main Post-Revert of Mistaken PR Merge
I accidentally merged a PR from my development branch (subject-serve-image) into the main branch instead of my release branch (rc/04). I quickly reverted that PR, which created another PR. I merged the revert PR back into main. Afterward, I created a new PR from my dev branch to the release branch (rc/04), which worked fine.
As part of my regular process, I merge my release branch (rc/04) into main periodically. However, when I created and merged the PR from rc/04 to main, it did not show any changes.
What could have gone wrong? What process should I have followed to ensure that the changes from the release branch merged correctly into main?

The step "I quickly reverted that PR" should instead have been "I quickly force-pushed the old main before anyone can notice and use the wrong merge."

Unfortunately or fortunately, here anyone was all me. I happen to have a habit of developing project this way, maintaining release branches and etc. :)

Nothing wrong with maintaining release branches and etc. Only that the correct fix for "oops, that merge was wrong" isn't "let's make a new commit that undoes the blunder", but it's "let's just start all over again".

Understood, pal. Feel free to drop in your thoughts on the correct solution. I know, I have one answer, I am happy to know if there is any other solution available.

Force pushing main to get rid of the commit isn't always a good idea.  If you have a big team, or even automated actions, you cannot count on getting the timing right.  And once that commit is in there, it can be painful to get everyone up-to-date in a way that does not contain it.  I don't think there's anything wrong with reverting the commit.  You just have to understand that reintroducing the change means redoing the commit so that it has a different commit id.

Also, if you really want to do a force push, I highly recommend using git push --force-with-lease to ensure the remote branch hasn't changed on you--otherwise you risk losing their changes.

Let's say your PR was trying to merge commit P.  When you accidentally merged it, that meant that main now also contains commit P.  Then you did a new PR that reverted P, call it Q and that was subsequently merged into main.  So at this point, main now contains P and Q.  Note that reverting here did not mean commit P never happened.  It means that Q was introduced to reverse the changes in P.
Next, you created a PR to do what you originally intended, to merge P into the rc/04.  Once merged, rc/04 now contains P.
When you get to the step of merging rc/04 into main, git will look at the set difference.  In this case, what does rc/04 bring that I don't already have in main.  Since P is present in both rc/04 and main, there are no commits to bring over.  Hence, the empty diff.
You'll want to make sure that main actually represents what you want though.  With Q reverting the changes, I'd bet the changes in P are not actually reflected on main.
One piece of advice is that when you end up reverting a commit and want to re-introduce the changes from that commit, it's best to create a new commit with the changes so that it gets a new ID number.  You can achieve that in a couple of ways: straight-up creating a new commit, or amending the commit (git commit --amend) with no change but updates the timestamp (you might need to use --reset-author to force the timestamp to change).  Once you have a new commit ID, git will no longer treat the commit as already being merged into main and you'd see the difference you expected.

Yeah, this makes sense.  That's what I had to do. I had to create new branch (fix-rc/04) off of rc/03 and do all the changes of rc/04 in that branch (fix-rc/04). It quickly gave off the changes/differences to the main branch.
You think any other process should have been followed?

It really depends on your team make up.  If your team is small and capable, then the suggesting of removing the commit entirely from main can be a good one.  But it really depends on your setup.  If you're good with rebasing in git, that's a good answer too.  You just need to make sure your desired commits are picked, because git will leave them off by default since they're already merged.  There really are many great answer to this scenario though. :-)

Thanks, mate. Appreciate your help. I need to be good with rebase yet. :)
